# Where to find some more specific information on Actions in Siri Shortcuts?

Tags: siri, ios12, sirishortcuts

There is a nice user guide on Shortcuts by Apple https://support.apple.com/guide/shortcuts/welcome/ios,  but there should be somewhere  some more datailed information as for example: what Pattern parameters may be used in "Match Text" action? Just some more precise definitions on Actions that may be used in the shortcuts. Anyone can help pointing to the right direction?